# CATextLayer and tracking / spacing  between characters

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, catextlayer

I am using CATextLayer , in order to using a custom font in iOS , I know there is simple way to using custom font with `Fonts provided by application` but this is different font . I was wondering is there any way to change the spacing between each characters ? I did not find any property to do so !

EDITED :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CTFontRef font = [self newCustomFontWithName:@"yeki" 
                                          ofType:@"ttf" 
                                      attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16.f] 
                                                                             forKey:(NSString *)kCTFontSizeAttribute]];


    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    normalTextLayer_ = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    normalTextLayer_.font = font;
    normalTextLayer_.string = str;
    normalTextLayer_.wrapped = YES;
    normalTextLayer_.foregroundColor = [[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor];
    normalTextLayer_.fontSize = 50.f;
    normalTextLayer_.alignmentMode =  kCAAlignmentRight;

    normalTextLayer_.frame = CGRectMake(0.f,100.f, screenBounds.size.width, screenBounds.size.height /1.f);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:normalTextLayer_];
    CFRelease(font);
}
```

Comment: You mean the kerning? You can try using `CGContextSetCharacterSpacing`.

Comment: yes , but I did not find any solution with `CGContextSetCharacterSpacing`  for CATextLayer class !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign an `NSAttributedString` (or `NSMutableAttributedString`) instead of a plain `NSString` to the layer and use the `kCTKernAttributeName` attribute (see [Core Text String Attributes Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html)) to adjust the kerning.

Example:

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 30, NULL);
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            (id)font, kCTFontAttributeName, 
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0], kCTKernAttributeName, 
                            (id)[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor], kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World" attributes:attributes] autorelease];
CFRelease(font);
myTextLayer.string = attributedString;
```

That should give you green text in Helvetica 30 with increased character spacing.

Comment: thank you . and would you please tell how can I use this : `kCTKernAttributeName` because when I replace my CATextLayer string with  `NSAttributedString` my text loose some effects like colors , custom fonts and etc ...

Comment: The color and font attributes of `CATextLayer` only apply to plain strings because an `NSAttributedString` defines its own attributes which can apply to different ranges within the string (different characters can have different colors...). You can use `initWithString:attributes` to initialize the attributed string with a dictionary of attributes that apply to the entire string. See the documentation that I linked to for an overview of available attributes.

Comment: Sorry I am little novice , I'v got this warning :`Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'const CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *const') to parameter of type 'id`  I would be really grateful if you show me how to do that

Comment: Added an example, I hope this helps.